# Create dynamic form angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/danywalls/dynamic-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fdynamic-field%2Fdynamic-radio%2Fdynamic-radio.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) example to create a dynamic form to reuse a component but i got some error

in the dynamic-field.component.ts file, exactly at those lines

```
const dynamicComponent = this.dynamicInputContainer.createComponent(componentInstance)
dynamicComponent.setInput('field', this.field);
```

when i click on a button to openn a dialog and create the form i got this error on the explorer console

```
ERROR TypeError: componentFactory.create is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:23175:1)
```

and in visual code i got

```
Property 'setInput' does not exist on type 'ComponentRef<unknown>'.ts(2339)
```

as comment i just read the code to understand it and i make copy paste so my code is the same as the stackblitz example
This is my first time creating a form like this way home someone can help me

Comment: The StackBlitz doesn't run for me. Anyone else having issues?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor It was just an failed import of a a service: `import { MessageService } from '/src/app/services/message.service'`... It will work by changing it to this:
`import { MessageService } from '../../../services/message.service';`(https://github-8ahits.stackblitz.io)